# Can't reference outer entry inside inner select query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a postgres database which contains two tables, one is a posts table which contains keywords and a _varchar of clip ids.
I also have a clips table which contains an _varchar of keywords.

I want to copy the keywords from the clips table to the keywords field in the posts table by using the ids in the clip_ids in the post table.

I've also added an extra where so that it only effects one posts row in case something breaks.

However when I try to do this I get the following error;

```
SQL Error [42P01]: ERROR: invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "posts"
  Hint: There is an entry for table "posts", but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query.
  Position: 143
```

from what I understand it refuses to allow me to reference the first entry of the clip ids array in the posts row. What am I doing wrong? Should I be following some other query structure?

```
update posts
set keywords = subquery.keywords 
FROM(SELECT keywords
FROM clips where id =posts.clips_ids[1]) as subquery
where id = 'c3d5345f-fa7b-413a-9e19-afccd950eb3c'
```

I'd appreciate any input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case I would put the subquery right into the assignment, as long as clips.id is a primary key:

```
update posts
set keywords = (SELECT keywords FROM clips where id =posts.clips_ids[1])
where id = 'c3d5345f-fa7b-413a-9e19-afccd950eb3c'
```